# Why won't my useEffect() hook fire when updating a react context value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why won't my `useEffect` hook fire when updating a dependency that uses a React context? I'm using a context as part of a wizard that will collect a bunch of data from a user and then eventually process this on the last wizard step.

The `Person` fields are being updated and on the next page of the wizard I'm able to retrieve them (not shown in my example for brevity). However I want to make an API call in the `useEffect` to perform some processing after the user has entered their name and address.

This is the code (it's a bit contrived):

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  skills: string[]; // collected on a different wizard page
};

const PersonContext = React.createContext(null);

const PersonProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useState<Person>({
    name: "",
    address: ""
  });

  return ( 
    <PersonContext.Provider value={personState}>
      {children}
    </PersonContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const PersonPage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const personState = useContext(PersonContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
  }, [personState]);
  
  /*
  Also tried, but no joy:

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
  }, [personState.name, personState.address]);
  */

  const onNameChanged = (e) => {
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(`name: ${e.target.value}`);
      personState.name = e.target.value;
    }
  };
  
  const onAddressChanged = (e) => {
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(`name: ${e.target.value}`);
      personState.address = e.target.value;
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      Name: <input name="name" onKeyDown={(e) => onNameChanged(e)} /> (press enter)
      <br />
      You typed: <span>{personState.name}</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      Address: <input name="address" onKeyDown={(e) => onAddressChanged(e)} /> (press enter)
      <br />
      You typed: <span>{personState.address}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <PersonProvider>
      <PersonPage />
    </PersonProvider>
  );
}
```

I've also got a CodePen example here:

> https://codepen.io/kevstercode/pen/gOexPea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component not re rendering when value from useContext is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838862/component-not-re-rendering-when-value-from-usecontext-is-updated)

Comment: Sadly not. That example doesn't use the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: You have the same underlying problem though: you're mutating your context object but not *changing* it. You need to call `setPersonState` instead of directly mutating `personState`. Your useEffect won't re-trigger because `personState` is still the same object (reference) as before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: [React Docs - Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: @Yousaf - I think I was so focused on the context docs I'd forgotten about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const PersonProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  // you should expose both the state object and its setter
  const personGetterSetter = useState<Person>({
    name: "",
    address: ""
  });

  return ( 
    <PersonContext.Provider value={personGetterSetter}>
      {children}
    </PersonContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
export const PersonPage: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  // unpack them here
  const [personState, setPersonState] = useContext(PersonContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
  }, [personState]);

  const onNameChanged = (e) => {
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(`name: ${e.target.value}`);

      // Wrong way to go
      // do not mutate state object directly

      // personState.name = e.target.value;

      // use the setter, this is the react way to update state
      setPersonState(personState => {
        return { ...personState, name: e.target.value }
      })
    }
  };
  
   ...
};
```

Comment: This did the trick thanks.

Comment: Just about to try this in my project (rather than a separate codepen)...if all good then I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You're mutating the object.
You should use the setState function to update it, eg.

instead of

```
const onAddressChanged = (e) => {
 if(event.key === "Enter") {
  personState.address = e.target.value;
 }
};
```

do this

```
const onAddressChanged = (e) => {
 if(event.key === "Enter") {
  setPersonState(prevState => {...prevState, address: e.target.value)}
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and +1, hackape just pipped you at the post with the mods to the `PersonProvider`.